# Не достаются объекты связных таблиц

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-jpa

Когда вытаскиваю user, то Set, Set всегда пустые, хотя в БД есть записи

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Tshirt> tshirts;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Cart> carts;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tshirts")
public class Tshirt {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

Comment: Можете показать где ваш запрос выполняется?(JpaRepository например), и не пробовали ли вы поменять Set на List?

Comment: Поменял Set на List и помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно поменять коллекцию Set на List.